# Check for missing number in sequence

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

I have an `List<int>` which contains 1,2,4,7,9 for example.

I have a range from 0 to 10.

Is there a way to determine what numbers are missing in that sequence?

I thought LINQ might provide an option but I can't see one

In the real world my List could contain 100,000 items so performance is key

Comment: As indicated in a comment to Andras, a Range of 1 million ints, and a list of 100,000, using Except (on my machine) takes 0.25 seconds. But we have no way of knowing if that's performant enough for you (and if not, what are acceptable performance limits?)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

```
var list = new List<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 4, 7, 9 });
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Except(list);
```

Comment: Definitely simple and clean - but speed concerns if the ranges are large

Answer (score 14):

Turn the range you want to check into a HashSet:

```
public IEnumerable<int> FindMissing(IEnumerable<int> values)
{
  HashSet<int> myRange = new HashSet<int>(Enumerable.Range(0,10));
  myRange.ExceptWith(values);
  return myRange;
}
```

Will return the values that aren't in `values`.

Comment: The reason I went for this is with large number sequences this should be faster as the hashset is reduced by iterating through the input list and removing each element.

The Except iterator method iterates the input collection for each element of the collection.

Comment: `HashSet<T>.ExceptWith` method does not return a value (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299875.aspx). It actually transforms the original hash.

Comment: Have update code sample - just realised that as you posted that comment!

Comment: If we really are doing ints, I just timed a range of a million ints and a list of 100000 known values, and the Linq Except (and I did remember to actually force enumeration) only took .25 seconds. Is that performant enough? Only OP knows.

Comment: @Damien - I'm always amazed at how fast the basic linq enumerations can actually be :)
It's most likely that OP isn't fussed about a few milliseconds here or there; I confess I'm a bit anal when it comes to that kind of thing!  That said - I haven't actually benchmarked the two side by side.

Comment: I have compared the 2 and the Hashset seems slower.  Thanks for all your help guys

Answer (score 4):

Using Unity i have tested two solutions on set of million integers. Looks like using Dictionary and two "for" loops gives better result than Enumerable.Except

FindMissing1 Total time: 0.1420 (Enumerable.Except)
FindMissing2 Total time: 0.0621 (Dictionary and two for loops)

```
public static class ArrayExtension
{
    public static T[] FindMissing1<T>(T[] range, T[] values)
    {
        List<T> result = Enumerable.Except<T>(range, values).ToList<T>();
        return result.ToArray<T>();
    }

    public static T[] FindMissing2<T>(T[] range, T[] values)
    {
        List<T> result = new List<T>();
        Dictionary<T, T> hash = new Dictionary<T, T>(values.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            hash.Add(values[i], values[i]);

        for (int i = 0; i < range.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!hash.ContainsKey(range[i]))
                result.Add(range[i]);
        }

        return result.ToArray<T>();
    }
}

public class ArrayManipulationTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        int rangeLength = 1000000;
        int[] range = Enumerable.Range(0, rangeLength).ToArray();
        int[] values = new int[rangeLength / 5];
        int[] missing;
        float start;
        float duration;

        for (int i = 0; i < rangeLength / 5; i ++)
            values[i] = i * 5;

        start = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        missing = ArrayExtension.FindMissing1<int>(range, values);
        duration = Time.realtimeSinceStartup - start;
        Debug.Log($"FindMissing1 Total time: {duration:0.0000}");

        start = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        missing = ArrayExtension.FindMissing2<int>(range, values);
        duration = Time.realtimeSinceStartup - start;
        Debug.Log($"FindMissing2 Total time: {duration:0.0000}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

LINQ's [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) method would be the most readable. Whether it performs adequately for you or not would be a matter for testing.

E.g.

```
range.Except(listOfValues);
```

*Edit*

Here's the program I used for my mini-benchmark, for others to plug away with:

```
static void Main()
{
    var a = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000);
    var b = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i += 10)
    {
        b.Add(i);
    }

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    var c = a.Except(b).ToList();
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Milliseconds {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds );
    sw.Reset();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: More than halfway there. Instead of just posting benchmark code you could post your results as well. The question has been answered but for others that come along and are curious about speed versus a `foreach` for example your answer then becomes useful if you have results.

Answer (score 3):

```
        List<int> selectedNumbers = new List<int>(){8, 5, 3, 12, 2};

        int firstNumber = selectedNumbers.OrderBy(i => i).First();
        int lastNumber = selectedNumbers.OrderBy(i => i).Last();

        List<int> allNumbers = Enumerable.Range(firstNumber, lastNumber - firstNumber + 1).ToList();

        List<int> missingNumbers = allNumbers.Except(selectedNumbers).ToList();

        foreach (int i in missingNumbers)
        {
            Response.Write(i);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method which works in general for **any** two [`IEnunumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where `T :`[`IComparable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable). If the IEnumerables are both sorted, this works in **O(1) memory** (i.e. there is no creating another [`ICollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13) and subtracting, etc.) and in **O(n) time**.

The use of `IEnumerable<IComparable>` and [`GetEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s793z9y2) makes this a little less readable, but far more general.

**Implementation**

```
/// <summary>
/// <para>For two sorted IEnumerable&lt;T&gt; (superset and subset),</para>
/// <para>returns the values in superset which are not in subset.</para>
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<T> CompareSortedEnumerables<T>(IEnumerable<T> superset, IEnumerable<T> subset)
    where T : IComparable
{
    IEnumerator<T> supersetEnumerator = superset.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator<T> subsetEnumerator = subset.GetEnumerator();
    bool itemsRemainingInSubset = subsetEnumerator.MoveNext();

    // handle the case when the first item in subset is less than the first item in superset
    T firstInSuperset = superset.First();
    while ( itemsRemainingInSubset && supersetEnumerator.Current.CompareTo(subsetEnumerator.Current) >= 0 )
        itemsRemainingInSubset = subsetEnumerator.MoveNext();

    while ( supersetEnumerator.MoveNext() )
    {
        int comparison = supersetEnumerator.Current.CompareTo(subsetEnumerator.Current);
        if ( !itemsRemainingInSubset || comparison < 0 )
        {
            yield return supersetEnumerator.Current;
        }
        else if ( comparison >= 0 )
        {
            while ( itemsRemainingInSubset && supersetEnumerator.Current.CompareTo(subsetEnumerator.Current) >= 0 )
                itemsRemainingInSubset = subsetEnumerator.MoveNext();
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var values = Enumerable.Range(0, 11);
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 4, 7, 9 };
var notIncluded = CompareSortedEnumerables(values, list);
```

Comment: Great solution, simple and fast.

Answer (score 1):

If the range is predictable I suggest the following solution:

```
public static void Main()
{
    //set up the expected range
    var expectedRange = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);

    //set up the current list
    var currentList = new List<int> {1, 2, 4, 7, 9};

    //get the missing items
    var missingItems = expectedRange.Except(currentList);       

    //print the missing items
    foreach (int missingItem in missingItems)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(missingItem);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Regards,
y00daa

Answer (score 1):

This does not use LINQ but it works in linear time.

I assume that input list is sorted.

This takes `O(list.Count)`.

```
private static IEnumerable<int> get_miss(List<int> list,int length)
{
    var miss = new List<int>();
    int i =0;
    for ( i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        foreach (var item in 
                     Enumerable.Range(list[i] + 1, list[i + 1] - list[i] - 1))
        {
            yield return item;
        }

    }
    foreach (var item in Enumerable.Range(list[i]+1,length-list[i]))
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

---

This should take `O(n)` where n is length of full range.

```
 static void Main()
    {
        List<int> identifiers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 4, 7, 9 };

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();
        List<int> miss = GetMiss(identifiers,150000);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}",sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    }
private static List<int> GetMiss(List<int> identifiers,int length)
{
    List<int> miss = new List<int>();

    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (i < identifiers[j])
            miss.Add(i);

        else if (i == identifiers[j])
            j++;

        if (j == identifiers.Count)
        {
            miss.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(i + 1, length - i));
            break;
        }
    }

    return miss;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, really, create a new list which parallels the initial list and run the method Except over it...

I have created a fully **linq** answer using the `Aggregate` method instead to find the missings:

```
var list = new List<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 4, 7, 9 }); // Assumes list is ordered at this point

list.Insert(0, 0);   // No error checking, just put in the lowest and highest possibles.
list.Add(10);        // For real world processing, put in check and if not represented then add it/them.

var missing = new List<int>();    // Hold any missing values found.

list.Aggregate ((seed, aggr) =>   // Seed is the previous #, aggr is the current number.
{
    var diff = (aggr - seed) -1;  // A difference between them indicates missing.

    if (diff > 0)                 // Missing found...put in the missing range.
        missing.AddRange(Enumerable.Range((aggr - diff), diff));

    return aggr;    
});
```

The missing list has this after the above code has been executed:

```
3, 5, 6, 8
```

Answer (score 1):

for a List L a general solution (works in all programming languages) would be simply

L.Count()*(L.Count()+1)/2 - L.Sum();

which returns the expected sum of series minus the actual series.

for a List of size n the missing number is:

n(n+1)/2 - (sum of list numbers)

Answer (score 0):

this method here returns the number of missing elements ,sort the set , add all elements from range 0 to range max , then remove the original elements , then you will have the missing set

```
int makeArrayConsecutive(int[] statues) 
{

Array.Sort(statues);    
HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>();

for(int i = statues[0]; i< statues[statues.Length -1]; i++)
 {
  set.Add(i);
 }

for (int i = 0; i < statues.Length; i++)
{
 set.Remove(statues[i]);
}

var x = set.Count;    
return x;
// return set ; // use this if you need the actual elements + change the method return type        
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create an array of num items

```
const int numItems = 1000;
bool found[numItems] = new bool[numItems];


List<int> list;

PopulateList(list);

list.ForEach( i => found[i] = true );

// now iterate found for the numbers found
for(int count = 0; i < numItems; ++numItems){
  Console.WriteList("Item {0} is {1}", count, found[count] ? "there" : "not there");
}
```

Comment: 1. You are forcing the use of a List<> object; 2. You are creating a very large intermediate object (your array of bools); 3. It's not a clean and readable solution, look at the others.

Comment: Thank you. I don't mind the answer being down voted I just wish I'd originally been told the reasons so I could learn. Again thank you

Answer (score -1):

This method does not use `LINQ` and works in general for any two `IEnunumerable<T> where T :IComparable`

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindMissing<T>(IEnumerable<T> superset, IEnumerable<T> subset) where T : IComparable
{
    bool include = true;
    foreach (var i in superset)
    {
        foreach (var j in subset)
        {
            include = i.CompareTo(j) == 0;
            if (include)
                break;
        }
        if (!include)
            yield return i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 int sum = 0,missingNumber;
        int[] arr = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += arr[i];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The sum from 1 to 10 is 55");
        Console.WriteLine("Sum is :" +sum);
        missingNumber =  55 - sum;
        Console.WriteLine("Missing Number is :-"+missingNumber);
        Console.ReadLine();
```