# find missing number from list of long

Tags: c#, linq

I have `List<long> MyList`  which contains long numbers like **7031320272 , 7031320273, 7031320277, 7031323700**
and a range, let's say [**7031320270, 7031324000**].

Now i want to find all the numbers in that range that are missing from `MyList`
I have already tried with `Enumerable.Range` without luck as it deals with only int values,
[as given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475795/c-sharp-check-for-missing-number-in-sequence)

## edit

I know the First and last number in the List. How to know the missing ones from the given range

Comment: Which number is missing?

Comment: your question is missing something? Can you try to make your question more clear..

Comment: @Satpal According to his example, I'd say he wants `7031320274`, `7031320275`, `7031320276`, `7031320278` and `7031320279`

Comment: What do you mean 'the missing numbers from this list'? in the example you've given, an infinite number of numbers are missing, all except the four you've given.

Comment: not infinite - it's a `List<long>` after all

Comment: is the input list ordered?

Comment: Yes infinite. While the numbers in the list are confined to being of type long, the numbers not in the list are not.

Comment: @RussellHorwood good point - I *assumed* the range of numbers would be constrained between `long.MinValue` and `long.MaxValue` (which seems to be a valid assumption in this case)

Comment: Yes, I think everybody correctly made that assumption. However as a mathematician I don't make assumptions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a similar approach as in the post you linked, just being explicit about the hashset used:

```
IEnumerable<long> GetMissingNumbers(long rangeStart, long rangeEnd, 
                                    IEnumerable<long> numbers)
{
    var existingNumbers = new HashSet<long>(numbers);

    for(long n = rangeStart;n<=rangeEnd;n++)
    {
        if(!existingNumbers.Contains(n))
            yield return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for using the Hashset. Once `numbers` becomes sufficiently long, lookup performance will become important.

Comment: It's an ordered input list, so you can do it even more efficiently without a hashset :D

Comment: @AndrewBarrett that wasn't part of the question when I answered - but it does not change the Big O in this case, if you assume hashset lookup is O(1)

Comment: @AndrewBarrett: I'm not sure about that; if it were a `SortedList<long>`, then yes, it would be more efficient without the hashset. But it simply being in order doesn't let the CLR know that it can stop looking once it passes the value it seeks. Unless I am mistaken, in which case I would love to better understand how `List` works behind the scenes.

Comment: Well I said efficiently which can mean more than Computational efficiency as you're duplicating the list in memory. Regardless, wasn't important.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we have:

```
List<long> FullList //Contains all numbers in range
List<long> MyList // My List
```

You can go for

```
var Missing = FullList.FindAll( x => !(MyList .Contains(x)));
```

Comment: you could simply use `FullList.Where(x=>!myList.Contains(x))` instead of FindAll

Answer (score 2):

Since `Range` only deals with ints, we just need to create a version that deals with longs:

```
public static IEnumerable<long> Range(long start, long count)
{
    for (long i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        yield return start++;
    }
}
```

Using that we can create the method you want easily enough:

```
public IEnumerable<long> GetMissingNumbers(long rangeStart, long rangeEnd,
                                IEnumerable<long> numbers)
{
    return Range(rangeStart, rangeEnd - rangeStart)
            .Except(numbers);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can make your own range method to return long values.

```
public static  IEnumerable<long> RangeLong(long start,long count)
{
    for(long l=start;l<=start+count;l++)
        yield return l;
}
```

There's no other method in linq to return range of long values.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```
List<long> FindMissing(List<long> theList, long lowerBound, long upperBound)
{
     var missVals = new List<long>();
     for(long x =lowerBound; x <= upperBound; x++)
         if(!theList.Contains(x)) 
              missVals.Add(x);
     return missVals;
}
```

or ...............................

```
List<long> FindMissing(List<long> theList, long lowerBound, long upperBound)
{      
     var missVals = new List<long>();
     while (lowerBound++ <= upperBound)
         if(!theList.Contains(lowerBound)) 
              missVals.Add(lowerBound);
     return missVals;
}
```

but this is still looping..

Comment: i don't want for loop, is dere something inbuild in Linq?

Comment: linq is just syntax,  a short cut in the source code only... It still loops